# Access rs:parameterLanguage URL parameter in RDL (Microsoft Sql Server Reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl, ssrs-2016

My software runs Sql Server Reporting Services (2008 and 2016) reports via url, like this:

http://{server}/ViewReport.aspx?U2APda1EzUd8PPkhPWzbckCJ8sUqU2anjuGibt9BQTtcSmXr7MeP5A%3d%3d&rs:Command=Render&rc:toolbar=true&rs:Format=html4.0&**rs:parameterLanguage={chosen culture code}**&rc:parameters=false&ProcVersion=17.2.3.0

I would like to display the parameterLanguage at the top of the resulting report, but I'm having trouble. Trying to display (in a textbox)

```
" Culture: " + rs:parameterLanguage
```

results in the following error:

```
The Value expression for the textrun ‘textbox58.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains a colon or a line terminator.
```

and this

```
" Culture: " + parameterLanguage
```

results in this error:

```
'parameterLanguage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

How can I access rs:parameterLanguage in the rdl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try parameters!parameterLanguage.value?

Comment: I get this error: The Value expression for the text box ‘textbox58’ refers to a non-existing report parameter ‘parameterLanguage’.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- it's

```
"Culture: " + User!Language
```

Which prints out  "Culture: en-US"